# Don't Reveal Full Path to Image, MVC

Tags: php, html, download

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to hide the actual download folder location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12707589/how-to-hide-the-actual-download-folder-location)

I have an img folder in each of my view folders, e.g. views/Login/img/myImage.png.

To echo that out as the source for an image tag I have to declare the full path to the image file on the server i.e. localhost:/mysite/public_html/views/Login/img/myImage.png.

Is there anyway around this where I don't have to use the full path?

Comment: What would you want to use?

Comment: You can use the relative path. This path depends on the folder where your webrootfolder is. E.g "/views/Login/img/myImage.png" Here's a Article about it: http://webdesign.about.com/od/beginningtutorials/a/aa040502a.htm

Comment: this has nothing to do with MVC nor with OOP.

Comment: you could use mod_rewrite to rewrite the paths to the images to the actual image. The outside world will then never see the true path.

Answer (score 0):

Using the answers of the following question:

[Reading filesystem and returning it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13383144/reading-filesystem-and-returning-it)

You are able to make an image caller script in your website root which will read the image file and return it as image.

```
mysite.com/getImages.php?src=Login/img/myImage.png
```

In this script you will add the prefix of the URL to the *src* query string.